# "Uncaught JavaScript error "Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on page" - TestCafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, try-catch, e2e-testing, testcafe

I work in a TestCafe testing program. The program repeats all user actions in the "record" mode, and then automatically repeats all previously recorded actions. But the problem. When you enter a numeric value in the input field, an error is displayed:

**"Uncaught JavaScript error "Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on page"**

I'm not strong in JS, all. TestCafe code, where I like to enter the desired number in the input field:

**"24.test": function() {
act.type(".input.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-isolate-scope.ng-empty", "0");
},**

And at the time of the automatic test run, the above error takes off. How to correct correctly or may be ignored. I've already tried using the **try{} catch(error){}** or **window bundle.onerror = function () {return true;}**. The error still crashes. I may not have inserted the code correctly into the function body.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, it is unclear why this error occurs. This error might be in your website itself and TestCafe just catches it.

Try running your tests with the 'Fail if a JavaScript error occurs on a page' option in [Run Configurations Dialog](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400189/user-interface/run-configurations-dialog) turned off and see if this error appears:

[image]

In addition, you can request the latest daily build from the [DevExpress Support Team](https://www.devexpress.com/sc) where this issue might be already fixed, or they will help you address it.